# In "Mono 3.0.10.20" what does 20 mean?

Tags: mono, versioning

I want to download the latest Mono MDK of the 3.0.10 branch.
On the [download site](http://download.mono-project.com/archive/3.10.0/macos-10-x86/), I see that 3 packages are available:

[image: Mono download versions]

**QUESTION:** What is the meaning of "20" in 3.10.0.20 ?

I find it strange that the 3.0.10.20 file is **older** than the 3.0.10.0 file.

The [Mono versioning scheme documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/versioning/) does **not** mention it.

Comment: X is just a placeholder...

Comment: @leppie: Yes, the placeholder was written by me. It is actually 20 or 19 or 0 or whatever you want.

Comment: Ahh, I would have assumed build number, but it could be an Android API level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 20 (or 19) is just a build number.

The package without the build number is probably supposed to be a copy of the latest package, and then someone forgot that when 3.10.0.20 was released (so it's identical to 3.10.0.19).